# Usage of Optional and Function

Tags: java, option-type

I am having troubles understanding the use of the Optional class in Java 8. I want to create an instance of a class (so I would use a Supplier) and then use .map() (so I need an Optional) to get another thing. My purpose is to write in a more “functional” way.
For example, I have this code:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public static Supplier<Optional<Something>> createSomething = () -> {
        Something sth = new Something();
        sth.setAttribute(“value”);
        return Optional.of(sth);
    }

    public static Function<Optional<Something>, Optional<Something>> doSomething = var -> {
        Something sth = var.get();
        sth.setAnotherAttribute(“anotherValue”);
        return Optional.of(sth);
    }
}
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

    public Optional<Something> method(){
        Optional<Something> sth = ParentClass.createSomething.get()
            .map(ParentClass::doSomething);
        return sth;

    }
}
```

There is an error:

```
The method map(ParentClass::doSomething) is undefined for the type Something
```

which I don’t understand why it happens. I tried removing the Optional wrapper but I still get the error message. Also tried writing the Function doSomething in the same ChildClass file but nothing happened. Can you see what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: "then use .map() (so I need an Optional)" Why do you think that using `.map()` requires an `Optional`? Why can't you just `return sth` instead of `return Optiona.of(sth)`?

Comment: It will help if you create a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and compile ourselves to see the exact same error.

Comment: `ParentClass#doSomething` is already a `Function`. You don't need to create a lambda from a `Function`. Instead, use it directly. This is: `ParentClass.createSomething.get().map(ParentClass.doSomething);`

Comment: FYI, you can declare `doSomething` as a `UnaryOperator<Optional<Something>>`, which would extend `Function<Optional<Something>, Optional<Something>>`.

Comment: Although @Michael Katt provided the answer in another comment, I will upload a minimal reproducible example to check it. Thank you all!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I uploaded an example here just in case somebody has the same question: https://github.com/tomprojects1/Optional-Example/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ParentClass` does not contain any methods but two static field member and that is a little bit confusing.

For this you can not use `doSomething` by method reference. You have to call the `doSomething.apply(Optional<Something>)`

For this reason ChildClass has to look like

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

   public Optional<Something> method() {
      Optional<Something> sth = ParentClass.doSomething.apply(ParentClass.createSomething.get());
      return sth;
   }
}
```

SUPPLEMENT

According to your further question you could use this solution. It looks a little bit weird but works.

```
public class ParentClass {

    public static Optional<Something> createSomething() {
        Something something = new Something();
        something.setAttribute("value");
        return Optional.of(something);
    }

    public static Something doSomething(Something something) {
        something.setAnotherAttribute("anotherValue");
        return something;
    }

    public static Something doMoreSomething(Something something) {
        something.setAnotherAttribute("anotherValue");
        return something;
    }
}
```

ChildClass does not need to inherit from ParentClass, if you are using static methods.

```
public class ChildClass {

    public Optional<Something> method() {

        Optional<Something> something = ParentClass.createSomething().map(ParentClass::doSomething)
                .map(ParentClass::doMoreSomething);

        return something;
    }
}
```

Your `doSomething` methods have to use `Something` and not `Optional<Something>` because `Optional.map` uses the wrapped value of the `Optional` inside. If you have an empty `Optional`, `map` is not executed. Be aware the `map` could return other `Optional` than `Optional<Something>` according to the return of your `doSomething` method, but it will be an `Optional`.

SUPPLEMENT 2

Here ChildClass using Inheritance for ParentClass non-static methods.

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public Optional<Something> method() {

        Optional<Something> something = createSomething().map(this::doSomething).map(this::doMoreSomething);

        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was writing an example to upload to Github when I saw your commment and actually solved it. So now I have another question: is this approach better/clearer than the traditional structured way? If I need to use another transformation (another Function like doSomething) it will get stranger and stranger.

Answer (score 1):

As [Luiggi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354322/usage-of-optional-and-function#comment120805616_68354322) points out, `doSomething` is already a `Function`; you don't need the method reference syntax. Also, `map()` expects a function on `Something`, not `Optional<Something>`. If you want to use a method reference, it would look like this:

```
public static Something doSomething(Something sth) {
    sth.setAnotherAttribute("anotherValue");
    return sth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example usage of `Optional::map`

Map using lambda

```java
class Test {
  private Function<Integer, String> convert = value -> value.toString();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var result = Optional.of(1).map(convert);
    // result now contains Optional with string "1"

    // Or alternatively
    var alternative = Optional.of(1).map(value -> value.toString());
  }
}
```

Map using method reference

```java
class Test {
  public static String convert(Integer value) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var result = Optional.of(1).map(Test::convert);
    // result now contains Optional with string "1"

    // Or alternatively
    var alternative = Optional.of(1).map(Objects::toString);
  }
}
```

Notice that both lambda function and method are not consuming nor producing value wrapped in `Optional`.

`Optional::map` then works that way, that if value stored within `Optional` is not `null` then it will apply on it provided function and its result will wrap again to `Optional` which will return.